# Tough to debug. Variables work in irb but the method fails

Tags: ruby, regex

I discovered a bug that without a trailing number [0-9], my method will fail. Therefore I used a quick gsub to insert that number.

I'm working with this method:

```
  def initialize(speciate)
     y = speciate.gsub(/$/, '1')
     x = y.scan(/[A-za-z]*\d+/)
     @chem_species = x.map { |chem| chem.scan(/[A-Z][^A-Z]*/) }.flatten
  end
```

When I test the variables in irb: (It works)

```
ruby-head > speciate = "NaCl"
 => "NaCl" 
ruby-head > y = speciate.gsub(/$/, '1')
 => "NaCl1" 
ruby-head > x = y.scan(/[A-za-z]*\d+/)
 => ["NaCl1"] 
ruby-head > @chem_species = x.map { |chem| chem.scan(/[A-Z][^A-Z]*/) }.flatten
 => ["Na", "Cl1"]
```

When I run the Method in irb: (It fails)

```
ruby-head > x = Chemical.new("NaCl")
 => #<Chemical:0x0000010084d0b8 @chem_species=[]> 
x = Chemical.new("H2SO4")
 => #<Chemical:0x000001008467e0 @chem_species=["H2", "S", "O4"]>
```

Thank you in Advance!

Comment: which version of ruby are you running?

Comment: My `ruby -v` is `ruby 1.9.1p378 (2010-01-10 revision 26273) [i386-darwin10]`.

Comment: What do you want the species to be for NaCl?  ["Na", "Cl"], I assume?

Comment: It works for me on ruby 1.8.7. But there's an error in your second regex: you almost certainly want `[A-Za-z]` instead of `[A-za-z]`.

Comment: Hey It works for 1.8.6 but not my Ruby-head; (I believe head is at 1.9.2) The error is it produces an empty array [] for NaCl in head

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since chemical symbols are always one uppercase letter, followed by zero or more lowercase letters, why not:

```
molecule = 'NaCl'
molecule.scan(/[A-Z][a-z]*[0-9]*/)
=> ["Na", "Cl"]

molecule = 'H2SO4'
molecule.scan(/[A-Z][a-z]*[0-9]*/)
=> ["H2", "S", "O4"]

molecule = 'Na2S'
molecule.scan(/[A-Z][a-z]*[0-9]*/)
=> ["Na2", "S"]

molecule = 'H'
molecule.scan(/[A-Z][a-z]*[0-9]*/)
=> ["H"]
```